# rxjs fundamentals | expecting subscription next to run once but runs multiple times

Tags: rxjs

```js
    fromEvent(document.querySelector('input[name=secondaryPhone]'), 'blur').pipe(
      first(),
      map(event => event.target['value']),
    ).subscribe(value => {
      debugger
      
    })
```

I've been working with and learning rxjs for over a month now and still have long way to go. Would anyone be able to explain to me why my debugger is triggered an equal amount of times as there was characters entered into the input? e.g., 123 4567 triggers the debugger 7 times (all with value = 123 4567). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It only runs once for me. This is not the event handler that is triggering the multiple debuggers for you.

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { first, map } = rxjs.operators;

fromEvent(document.querySelector('input[name=secondaryPhone]'), 'blur').pipe(
  first(),
  map(event => event.target['value']),
).subscribe(value => {
  console.log('blur ' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<input name="secondaryPhone">
```